# Merge arrays with condition

Tags: arrays, swift, function, loops, swift3

I would like to merge two arrays with specific condition and update objects that they are containing.

First my struct that is in arrays:

```
struct Item {
    var id:Int
    var name:String
    var value:Int
}
```

Second elements for the two arrays:

```
let fisrt = Item(id: 1, name: "Oleg", value: 3)
let second = Item(id: 2, name: "Olexander", value:5)

let fisrtInSecond = Item(id: 1, name: "Bogdan", value: 6)
let secondInSecond = Item(id: 2, name: "Max", value: 9)
```

Arrays:

```
 var fisrtArray = [fisrt, second]
 let secondArray = [fisrtInSecond, secondInSecond]
```

I woudl like to use `zip` and `map` functions of the collection to achive result. Result is that `fisrtArray`  elements `names` are updated by `id`.

Example: `fisrtArray = [Item(id: 1, name: "Bogdan", value:3), Item(id: 2, name: "Max", value:5)]`

I know how to do this via simple loops. But i am looking for more advanced usage of the functional programing is Swift.

My experiment:

```
fisrtArray = zip(fisrtArray, secondArray).map()
```

The main problem i do not know how to write condition in the `map` function. Condition should be:

```
if ($0.id == $1.id) {
   $0.name = $1.name
}
```

**From the comment discussing it is possible to highlight that `zip` is not suitable in my case because we should iterate over all array to find if we have similar id's that are not in the same order.**

Comment: What if the item with id 2 comes first in the second array?

Comment: Hmm you are right we should iterate over all array to find if we have similar id's

Comment: So you cannot use zip(), you have to lookup each time from the first array in the second array. How large are the arrays?

Comment: Array are no more than 20 elements

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code does work independently by the order of the elements inside the 2 arrays

```
firstArray = firstArray.map { (item) -> Item in
    guard
        let index = secondArray.index(where: { $0.id == item.id })
        else { return item }
    var item = item
    item.name = secondArray[index].name
    return item
}
```

> "[Item(id: 1, name: "Bogdan", value: 3), Item(id: 2, name: "Max", value: 5)]\n"

### Update

*The following version uses the `first(where:` method as suggested by `Martin R.`*

```
firstArray = firstArray.map { item -> Item in
    guard let secondElm = secondArray.first(where: { $0.id == item.id }) else { return item }
    var item = item
    item.name = secondElm.name
    return item
}
```

Comment: As of Swift 3 you can also use `secondArray.first(where: { $0.id == item.id })` to find the first matching *element.*

Comment: @MartinR: Very useful, just added it to my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

A solution for your specific problem above would be:

```
struct Item {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
}

let first = Item(id: 1, name: "Oleg")
let second = Item(id: 2, name: "Olexander")

let firstInSecond = Item(id: 1, name: "Bogdan")
let secondInSecond = Item(id: 2, name: "Max")

let ret = zip([first, second], [firstInSecond, secondInSecond]).map({
    return $0.id == $1.id ? $1 : $0
})
```

---

*=> But it requires that there are as many items in the first as in the second array - and that they have both the same ids in the same order...*

Answer (score 1):

The `map` function cannot directly mutate its elements. And since you're using structs (passed by value), it wouldn't work anyway, because the version you see in $0 would be a different instance than the one in the array. To use `map` correctly, I'd use a closure like this:

```
fisrtArray = zip(fisrtArray, secondArray).map() {
   return Item(id: $0.id, name: $1.name, value: $0.value)
}
```

This produces the result you're expecting.

Now, if your structs were objects (value types instead of reference types), you could use `forEach` and do the `$0.name = $1.name` in there.