# Subtract of two arrays of objects based on the properties of objects

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Say I have 2 arrays of instances of class "Person". Class Person has properties "name", "age", "id". "id" is a unique identifier, so can be used for comparing of people. 
So, say I have two arrays of people:

```
[ {Name: Bob,Age: 18,ID: 142353}, {Name: Rob, Age: 40,ID: 142350}, {Name: Andy, Age: 30,ID: 142359}, {Name: Andy, Age: 21,ID: 142340}  ]

[ {Name: Jack,Age: 18,ID: 142362}, {Name: James, Age: 40,ID: 142311}, {Name: Rob, Age: 40,ID: 142350}, {Name: Andy, Age: 21,ID: 142340}  ]
```

I want to compare the IDs of people and get those, that are different in array 1 from that in array 2, so the result should look like:

```
[{Name: Bob,Age: 18,ID: 142353}, {Name: Andy, Age: 30,ID: 142359}]
```

The way I am doing this now in Swift is:

```
   let new = newPeople.filter({ p1 in
                        previousPeople.contains(where: { p2 in
                            p1.id != p2.id
         })
   })
```

But I don't think this is working. Can't figure out what is wrong with my implementation.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge arrays with condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263697/merge-arrays-with-condition)

Comment: `let new = newPeople.filter({ p1 in !previousPeople.contains(where: { p2 in p1.id == p2.id }) })`

Comment: Please use trailing closure syntax to avoid having `})` everywhere

Comment: @IlyaLapan You should post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we don't have to waste our time recreating your data structure.

Answer (score 4):

You want to conform your Person class to Equatable protocol.

```
extension Person: Equatable {
    static func ==(lhs: Person, rhs: Person) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
}
```

then you can do a simple filter of the two arrays:

```
let person1 = Person(name: "J", age: 20, id: UUID())
let person2 = Person(name: "K", age: 40, id: UUID())
let person3 = Person(name: "L", age: 30, id: UUID())
let person4 = Person(name: "M", age: 25, id: UUID())
let person5 = Person(name: "N", age: 39, id: UUID())

let personArray1 = [person1, person2, person3]
let personArray2 = [person4, person2, person3]

let filteredPersonArray = personArray1.filter { !personArray2.contains($0) }
//filteredPersonArray.count == 1 which is person4
```

Comment: Your indentation was all over the place. I edited and fixed it for you.

Comment: Great answer, but I suggest you use a set.

Comment: thanks, Alexander, I'm still getting a hang of the formatting. Good suggestion with the set, I didn't think of that.

Comment: Without using a `Set`, this algorithm is `O(N^2)`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a `Set` of the ids you don't want to keep, and filter your people by checking `contains` against this `Set`. You can obtain an `Array` of ids from an `Array` of people by using `people.map{ $0.id }`.

```
struct Person {
    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let id: Int
}

let people1 = [
    Person(name: "Bob", age: 18, id: 142353),
    Person(name: "Rob", age: 40, id: 142350),
    Person(name: "Andy", age: 30, id: 142359),
    Person(name: "Andy", age: 21, id: 142340)
]

let people2 = [
    Person(name: "Jack", age: 18, id: 142362),
    Person(name: "James", age: 40, id: 142311),
    Person(name: "Rob", age: 40, id: 142350),
    Person(name: "Andy", age: 21, id: 142340)
]


let undesiredIDs = Set(people2.map{ $0.id })
print("Keeping all people that don't have one of these IDs: \(undesiredIDs)\r\n\r\n")

let filteredPeople = people1.filter{ !undesiredIDs.contains($0.id) }

print("Original list: \(people1).\r\n\r\n")
print("Filtered: \(filteredPeople)")
```