# How Filter Custom Object Array with Condition

Tags: arrays, swift, swift3

I have Item Class

```
 class Item {
        var id:Int
        var name:String
        var value:Int
        var isDefault:Bool
    }
```

On basis of Class Item i have 2 array of [Item] class i want to merge this array with replacing object in first array with second if id is matched and all remaining array in (first/second) should be appended

```
let fisrt = Item(id: 1, name: "A", value: 3, isDefault:false)
let second = Item(id: 2, name: "B", value:5,isDefault:false)
let third = Item(id: 3, name: "c", value:5,isDefault:false)

var fisrtArray = [fisrt, second, third]

let fisrt2 = Item(id: 4, name: "P", value: 13, isDefault:true)
let second2 = Item(id: 2, name: "Q", value:15, isDefault:true)
let third2 = Item(id: 7, name: "R", value:15,  isDefault:true)
let forth2 = Item(id: 8, name: "S", value:18,  isDefault:true)

var secondArray = [fisrt2, second2, third2,forth2]
```

So my Resulted Array should be

```
Item(id: 1, name: "A", value: 3, isDefault:false)
Item(id: 2, name: "Q", value:5,isDefault:true)
Item(id: 3, name: "c", value:5,isDefault:false)
Item(id: 4, name: "P", value: 13, isDefault:true)
Item(id: 7, name: "R", value:15,  isDefault:true)
Item(id: 8, name: "S", value:18,  isDefault:true)
```

> Note: size of array may be any thing either firstArray is large or
>   Second its not dependent. I do it with for loop but i think there other way of doing it

Comment: [Duplicate] check out this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40263697/merge-arrays-with-condition

Comment: i have no two array of same sized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let result = secondArray
result.append(contentsOf: fisrtArray.filter { item in
    !secondArray.contains(where: { $0.id == item.id })
})
```

After that you can sort the `result` by `id`